# Find the size of array outside of main function in C

Tags: arrays, c, function

Please take a look at the minimal code example below. I've noticed a behavior in C that I cannot find an explanation for, so I decided to post a question here.

**Case 1**

The goal was to declare and initialize an array in `main`, and then pass it to `function1`. The trick was to then find the number of elements of that array in `function1` without having to first calculate it in `main`, and then pass it as the argument. That did **not** work.

**Case 2 and Case 3**

Here, I calculate the number of elements in the array in `main`, and then pass it as the argument in `function2`. That works perfectly.

**Question**

My question is not necessarily why this process of calculating the number of elements in an array does not work in functions other than `main`; that kind of makes sense.

My understanding is that the array is nothing but the pointer to the first element (in this case `double *`). The size of such pointer (at least on my computer architecture) is 8 bytes. So, `sizeof(a) = 8`. This is also the same as size of any one of the elements (`sizeof(a) == sizeof(a[0])`). Thus, I will always get that `numOfElements == 1`.

*My question is rather what makes `main` so special that it knows how to "properly" answer my query regarding `sizeof(a)`*. Particularly, since I had an array of 4 doubles, main will tell me that `sizeof(a) == 32`, which is exactly what I needed to calculate `numOfElements`.

*Also, why is GCC giving me the warning? Does it know that I will not get the value I am actually looking for?*

Thank you to anyone who advances my knowledge. I apologize if the answer is rather obvious. Perhaps, I am looking at this from a bit too abstract point of view than needed to analyze this behavior.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function1(double a[])
{
    int numOfElements = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

    printf("\n ---> Size of array in function1: %d\n", sizeof(a));

    // Some operations...
}

void function2(double a[], int numOfElements)
{
    // Some operations...
}

int main()
{
    double a[] = {1.32, 2, 5.52, 9.99};
    
    // Case 1
    function1(a);

    // Case 2
    int numOfElements = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    function2(a, numOfElements);
    
    // Case 3 - a more compact version of Case 2
    function2(a, sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]));

    printf("\n ---> Size of array in main: %d\n", sizeof(a));
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Output and Warning**

[image]

Comment: `void function1(double a[])` is actually `void function1(double *a)` - therefore no size information is received via the argument

Comment: There is a difference between arrays and pointers in C. Inside main, `a` is treated as an array. Inside functions, it's effectively a pointer.

Comment: Sorry, this is not "how do i get size of my array" question, OP already knows, The question is about why that happens in main and not in the called function. Voted to re-open, feel free to revert with a suitable dupe, as applicable.

Comment: the duplicate does not address why sizeof is not working with function parameters as well as how to get the size of an parameter array (spoiler: you can't because there are no such thing parameters of type array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about `main()`, as long as you are not passing an array as function argument, you are okay.

In other words, **[arrays are not pointers and vice-versa](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/)**. However, when an array is passed as a function argument, it decays to the pointer to the first element, so using `sizeof` on the received parameter inside the called function does not yield the expected result.

However, in the same function where the array is defined, it's still an array, and using `sizeof` returns the expected size. So, it's not specific about `main()`, it's about passing the array as function argument or not.